# Bicycle trailer for a standing passenger?

Tags: identify-this-bike

Have you seen a bicycle trailer for a standing passenger?
I came across the following image on Pinterest but cannot locate the source.
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/453737731186785705/

[image: Inline image]

Answer (score 10):

Appears to be asian based on the rider/passenger, and that pintrest links it to `arrow-yokohama.no-blog.jp`  but that website no longer exists.

The wayback machine gives us this link to 2013. 
  https://web.archive.org/web/20130809133057/http://arrow-yokohama.no-blog.jp/

- Store Name: "ARROW's bicycles and classics"
- Store Owner: Kazuto Kobayashi ( Roundabout / OUTBOUND shopkeeper
- Store Location: Kichijōji, a Neighborhood in [Musashino, Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kichij%C5%8Dji)

There was a youtube link to  `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lt75V_C5JOI`  but that account has been deleted.

I've also found this alternative image: 
 [image: http://cfs12.blog.daum.net/image/31/blog/2008/08/28/07/42/48b5d867226b4&filename=080709raygun06.jpg]

and a reverse image search on that returns https://sumally.com/p/437518

The bike's name is  **ARROW CC Rider** and that matches the maker's name "arrow"

[image]
  36,750 Y is around $350 USD in 2020.

[image]

> Product description
>   The person in the back grabs the handle and stands on the step.
>   Light and comfortable standing (riding) comfort. You can also use it as a shopping cart by attaching a basket.
>   Please ride cool as a new play tool for the outdoors.
>   (General public roads can also be run.)

---

In my opinion it won't go fast, and steering will be compromised because you can't lean the bike very much.   It looks like a bigger version of riding a BMX with a passenger on the pegs, a`la:
[image]

Comment: Probably not road-legal in Europe due to compromised stability. Regulations also stipulate that passengers in a trailer must be seated.

Comment: Definitely the pegs is a much more efficient solution (less added weight in order to carry someone. Probably adding a larger surface on the pegs for standing would make it more comfortable. I've also seen a rear rack with padding for the passenger to seat on. This is how my grandpa used to take grandma to/from work. She would seat with both legs on the same side of the bike.

Comment: @Jahaziel perhaps - but that's 1.5 riders body weight on the one rear wheel.  Probably OK for kids but still adds up.  Also, OP's trailer ("chariot??")  can be used as a parcel trailer too.

Comment: @Criggie You are absolutely right. If the O.P. is asking for the trailer they probably think if transporting someone very frequently. I just wanted to contrast that the pegs or a rack weight less and do not add much to the size of the bike (Thinking of storage and locking the bike at home or at work). My grandfather's bike was a "flying pigeon" or similar, and was plenty capable of carrying more than one adult's weight.

Comment: The trailer on the other hand, has indeed the advantage that once removed from the bike means almost no extra weight and no added bulk on the bike (except maybe for a connector) and when in use would not put a significative extra load on the bike.